# What happen if i create one secondary index and add all keys in one secondary index instead of 16 secondary index in Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

So Basically I have 16 secondary index in Spanner Table. While Api is retrieving Data from Spanner table, the latency is very much high. We have already provided enough spanner node and size of the table is around 5GB. So instead of 16 secondary index, will that thing work if I create 1 single index and add all the keys in 1 index.

Comment: Are your queries being performed through the secondary indexes, or can you give an example of a query with high latency? I ask because usually secondary indexes help with the speed of commonly performed queries.

Comment: I known secondary index improve the performance, and the query being performed on secondary index still it's taking around 37 seconds to get the result.

Comment: For what you describe here and on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154576/facing-latency-issues-while-fetching-data-in-spanner-table), it seems that you may need to either improve your queries by following [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices) or maybe you have an [Anti-pattern](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#primary-key-prevent-hotspots) on your database. However it's hard to know for sure without knowing the specifics of your tables and queries.

Comment: I just have 1 filter condition on secondary-index. Nothing much on query side.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your Schema then? As I mentioned there may be a hotspot on your tables and that may be the reason for the slow query.

Comment: @rsalinas Here I have around 40-50 columns out of which there are 2 primary id's and we are creating 16 secondary index on different column present in table.