# Facing latency issues while fetching data in Spanner table

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have few spanner tables where I'm facing latency issue while fetching rows through API's. So we are using secondary index for multiple tables, as it improves the performance. We are using around 50 spanner nodes and average utilisation is around 60% and the query being performed are on top of secondary index. Spanner table has 16 secondary index. With all this functionality on place, we are still facing latency issue as query took around 37 seconds to complete. Query is not the complicated one, just have one filter condition.
I don't want what's going wrong in my case.

Comment: Please add following details, which can help narrow down the issue: - How many records are in the table and how many of those are returned by the query after the filter?
- How does schema look like for the table and secondary index used for query?
- What is the exact query that you are performing?

Comment: Is it possible to fetch 1million records in single spanner read query?

Comment: This question needs more detail on what the actual query is and what the schema looks like. The long query time could for example be caused by a filter condition that does not match any of your indexes, even if you have a large number of indexes on your tables.